# Upload Image File to server

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Have a little problem with uploar file image to server

That is JS code for ajax send file to server

/**
     *
     * Init Crope Image
     *
     */

```
    $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
        files = this.files;
    });

    $('#upload_photo').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Остановка происходящего
        event.preventDefault();  // Полная остановка происходящего

        var data = new FormData();
        $.each( files, function( key, value ){
            data.append( key, value );
        });

        var obj = {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name^="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
            action: 'upload_photo',
            file: data
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: /user_ajax_set_photo/,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function( response, textStatus, jqXHR ){

                if( response.error === 'false' ){

                    console.log('Загружен' + response.error );

                }
                else{
                    console.log('ОШИБКИ ОТВЕТА сервера: ' + response.error );
                }
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
            }
        });
    });
}
```

That us my View

```
def user_ajax_set_photo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileUploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print 'valid form'
        else:
            print 'invalid form'
            print form.errors
    return True
```

And for last that is my Form

```
class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = RegModel
        fields = ['image']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(FileUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        photo = super(FileUploadForm, self).save(commit=False)
        artist = RegModel.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        photo.artist = artist
        photo.save()
        return photo
```

Can u tell me where is my promlems...

Last error from backtrase

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: What's the line and file where that error occurs?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 32, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your view must return some kind of Django Response object.  Given that you're using AJAX here, I'm guessing you'd want to use the JSONResponse object:

```
from django.http import JSONResponse

def user_ajax_set_photo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileUploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print 'valid form'
        else:
            print 'invalid form'
            print form.errors
    return JSONResponse([True], safe=False)
```

Note that in JSON you can't just have a floating Boolean value, so I wrapped that in an array.  By default, when you pass a non-dict object into JSONResponse, you have to also pass `safe=False`.